# Automation Error on "VBProject.VBComponents"- VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I have this code:

```
Sub ChangeImportedBOQCodeName(importedName As String)
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveSheet.CodeName).Name = "BOQ_" & importedName
End Sub
```

That is called from

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

    Dim TargetName As String

    TargetName = cbxSheets.Text

    Set TargetSheet = TargetWB.Sheets(TargetName)
    TargetSheet.Copy After:=SourceWB.Sheets(SourceSheet.Index)

    ChangeImportedBOQCodeName ActiveSheet.CodeName

    ' Close the User Form
    Unload Me

    ' Inform User on Successful BOQ Import
    MsgBox "The selected BOQ was successfully imported to the Analysis", vbInformation, "Import Successful"

    ' Ask User to generate codes automatically
    Dim msgTxt As String
    msgTxt = "Generate codes in the imported BOQ, automatically ?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
             "(The proccess may take a while depending on the System specs and BOQ layout and size)"

    If MsgBox(msgTxt, vbYesNo, "Auto Code BOQ") = vbYes Then
        CheckImportedBOQ ActiveSheet
    Else
        MsgBox "Auto code genrate was aborted", vbInformation, "Aborted"
    End If

End Sub
```

But I am getting this error:

> Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)'  Automation error The object
>   invoked has disconnected from its client

And excel exits abruptly.

Problem is that this error never occurred before and the code was working very fine.

I also tried commenting `ChangeImportedBOQCodeName ActiveSheet.CodeName` this line and the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Sub ChangeImportedBOQCodeName` you are passing `ActiveSheet.CodeName`, so all you need to do is change:

```
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveSheet.CodeName).Name = "BOQ_" & importedName
```

To:

```
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(importedName).Name = "BOQ_" & importedName
```